# Git Checksum is not changing

Tags: java, git, gradle, azure-pipelines

I would like my Azure DevOps to build the project whenever i make changes inside or outside my src folder. As of now, the build is triggered only when i make changes inside my src folder. So i decided to use checksum to detect the changes happening in the project.

Currently, I have a checksum script like the one below in my Azure DevOps Pipeline for my Java Spring Boot Project.

```
checksum=$(git rev-parse HEAD:build.gradle $(git ls-files -- ':!HEAD:${{parameters.sourceDirectory}}/' ':HEAD:${{parameters.sourceDirectory}}/**'))
```

Whenever I make changes inside src file, it's automatically changing. But whenever I make changes outside src, the checksum is not impacted. How to make the checksum change during every commit, irrespective of changes happening inside or outside src folder?

I also tried the below script which didnt work as well.

```
checksum=$(git rev-parse HEAD:${{parameters.sourceDirectory}}/HEAD:build.gradle)
```

Comment: If you want a value that changes with every commit irrespective of what changes happened, why not just use the commit id via a simple `git rev-parse HEAD`?

Comment: It sounds more like you want to generate a UUID or other large random value each time instead of a checksum. Or just the time in milisecond precision. I mean if it should be different even if `src` isn’t.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Tried but didnt work

Comment: @Guildenstern The requirement here is the build has to be triggered whenever a change is commited in the repo. Now its triggering only the changed happened inside src folder. Basically I am using checksum change to initiate build.gradle . Coz i expect the checksum to change on every git commit.

Comment: What's the difference between "changes inside or outside my src folder" and just "changes"? Is the `src` folder even relevant?

Comment: Why even require a "checksum"? New commit => run build.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment:

> ***The requirement here is the build has to be triggered whenever a change is committed in the repo. Now its triggering only the changed happened inside `src` folder.***

You can go to check if there are any [**Path filters**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#paths) set on the CI trigger of your build pipeline.

1. For classic build pipeline, on the '**Trigger**' tab of pipeline settings, ensure you do not set any **Path filters** on the enabled CI (continuous integration) trigger.

   - **Enable continuous integration:** Enable CI trigger.
   - **Branch filters:** Set [**Branch filters**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers). If you want the build can be triggered when pushing changes to any branches in the source git repository on Azure Repos, you can set the value of "**`Branch specification`**" as "**`*`**".
   - **Path filters:** Set **Path filters**. If you want the build can be triggered when pushing changes to any files, do not add any **Path filters**.

   [image]
2. For YAML pipeline, you need to check the filters in two places.

   - Go to the '**Trigger**' tab on UI settings page, check if you have enabled CI trigger and added filters on this UI page. Any triggers and filters set on this page will override the triggers set in the YAML file. It is recommended not enable any triggers on this page if you want to maintain the triggers in YAML files.

   [image]

   - Open the YAML file that define the pipeline, check if there are any **Path filters** defined to the CI trigger.

     ```yaml
     # Set CI trigger.
     # No Path filters set. Will trigger when pushing changes to any files.
     trigger:
       branches:
         include:
         - '*'  # Trigger when pushing changes to any branches.
     ```

     If you do not explicitly set the CI trigger in the YAML file, by default, the build can be triggered when pushing changes to any branches and any files.

     **NOTE:** If you want the build can be triggered when pushing changes to any branches, you also need to ensure the YAML file exists on all branches. If you want the build can be triggered when pushing changes to a specified branch, the YAML files should exist on that branch at least.

---